# PHP Countdown without seconds

Tags: php, countdowntimer

I use this countdown script, to count down to 5pm ever day. How can I print the time without the seconds?

```
<?php
            function formatTime($unixtime) {
                return date("H:i", $unixtime);
            }

            function formatSeconds($seconds) {
                $time = str_pad(intval(intval($seconds/3600)),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).":"
                . str_pad(intval(($seconds / 60) % 60),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).":"
                . str_pad(intval($seconds % 60),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT) ;
                return $time;
            }

            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
            $hour_in_english = "5pm";
            $passed_message = "Bestel nu en je bestelling vertekt morgen!";
            $future_message = "Bestel binnen ";
            $future_message_2 = " en je bestelling vertrekt vandaag!";
            $time_now = strtotime("now");
            $time_hour = strtotime("today {$hour_in_english} ");
            $difference_in_seconds = $time_hour - $time_now;
            if ($difference_in_seconds < 0) {
                print $passed_message;
            } else {
                print $future_message . formatSeconds($difference_in_seconds) . $future_message_2;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Just wondering why you are using PHP for this, and not javascript?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot make use of javascript on that page. So I need to use PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you just have to remove a code from the formatSeconds function. Here is the updated code that will just print the time without the seconds.

```
<?php 
        function formatTime($unixtime) {
                return date("H:i", $unixtime);
            }

            function formatSeconds($seconds) {
                $time = str_pad(intval(intval($seconds/3600)),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).":"
                . str_pad(intval(($seconds / 60) % 60),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
                return $time;
            }

            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
            $hour_in_english = "5pm";
            $passed_message = "Bestel nu en je bestelling vertekt morgen!";
            $future_message = "Bestel binnen ";
            $future_message_2 = " en je bestelling vertrekt vandaag!";
            $time_now = strtotime("now");
            $time_hour = strtotime("today {$hour_in_english} ");
            $difference_in_seconds = $time_hour - $time_now;
            if ($difference_in_seconds < 0) {
                print $passed_message;
            } else {
                print $future_message . formatSeconds($difference_in_seconds) . $future_message_2;
            }

?>
```